# OpenMapTiles Server - How to update data?

Tags: openmaptiles

I've installed OpenMapTiles Map Server.  The step-by-step setup works for importing data, and everything works as shown in the videos.

How can I change the current data set without first deleting the current dataset?

I tried downloading data from https://openmaptiles.com/downloads but got a message saying that the data has to be downloaded directly into the OpenMapTiles Map Server.

Answer (score 0):

when you use docker, you can delete the mapped data folder. I don't know but it works .p

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [TileServer GL documentation](http://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) you can specify the location of the mbtiles-file via the [Configuration file](http://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) or simply move the mbtiles-file away from current working directory.